# I want to merge values of a nested Json object with javascript:

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, array-merge

So How to merge values of a Json object like this:
`{"zz0": "value 1","zz1": "value 2","zz2": "value 3"}`
into this:
`{"key":["value 1","value 2","value 3"]}`
In my javascript form this is the first Json file:

```
    [
        {
            "fotos": [
                {
                    "foto": "foto 1",
                    "zz0": "first line.",
                    "zz1": "second line.",
                    "zz2": "third line."
                },
                {
                    "foto": "foto 2",
                    "zz0": "first line."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

And this is the second Json File:

```
    [
        {
            "fotos": [
                {
                    "foto": ["foto 1"],
                    "tekst": ["first line.", "second line.", "third line."]
                },
                {
                    "foto": ["foto 2"],
                    "tekst": ["first line."]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Searched a solution with map and arrow functions but got stuck... Any idea?

Comment: What logical representation are you after? The example you provided isn't logically clear, all keys are different so how do you logically group the keys together? Ex: `{"zz0": "value 1","zz1": "value 2","zz2": "value 3"}` into this: `{"key":["value 1","value 2","value 3"]}`

Comment: The keys 'zz0', 'zz1' and 'zz2' should be replaced by 1 key: 'key' and their values put together as values for 'key' (in the big example: 'tekst')

Comment: do objects only contain one property `foto` and many properties `zz*`? I mean, are there more properties?

Comment: in 'fotos' each single 'foto' has many lines 'tekst'

Comment: At the moment I see 3 nice solutions by Asraf, GrafiCode and Carsten Massmann. But my programming knowledge is not big enough to choose the best solution. In addition, I wonder if there are pros and cons or does it not matter much?

Comment: @backnext I think my solution IS NOT as performant as the others, you should choose between the others

Comment: @GrafiCode Tanx for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{ "fotos": [{ "foto": "foto 1", "zz0": "first line.", "zz1": "second line.", "zz2": "third line." }, { "foto": "foto 2", "zz0": "first line." }]}];

const ans = arr.map(({fotos}) => ({fotos: fotos.map(({foto, ...res}) =>({foto: [foto], tekst: Object.values(res)}))}));

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array.map()`, `Object.keys()` anf `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const data = [{
  "fotos": [{
      "foto": "foto 1",
      "zz0": "first line.",
      "zz1": "second line.",
      "zz2": "third line."
    },
    {
      "foto": "foto 2",
      "zz0": "first line."
    }
  ]
}]

const res = data[0].fotos.map(obj => {
  const tekst = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,key) => {
    if (key != 'foto') { acc.push(obj[key]) }
    return acc
  }, [])
  
  return { foto: [obj.foto], tekst: tekst }
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Works good and very nice. Thanx. Maybe I prefer the solution of Astraf...

Comment: @Asraf's solution is my favourite too!

Answer (score 1):

The following would do the job:

```js
const dat=[
    {
        "fotos": [
            {
                "foto": "foto 1",
                "zz0": "first line.",
                "zz1": "second line.",
                "zz2": "third line."
            },
            {
                "foto": "foto 2",
                "zz0": "first line."
            }
        ]
    }
];

const res=dat[0].fotos.map(f=>({foto:f.foto,key:Object.entries(f).filter(a=>a[0]!='foto').map(a=>a[1])}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: apparently I have a choice of several perfectly working and brilliant options here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge them like this with reduce

```
const a = {a: 2, b: 3, c: 4}
Object.keys(a).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc['key'].push(a[key])
    return acc
}, {'key': []})
```

this would give you `{'key': [2, 3, 4]}`